# Inexplicable watchOS 2 Error

Tags: syntax-error, watchkit, swift2, watchos-2, xcode7-beta4

So I have my watch app asking for text input as is below but it gets this error that makes NO sense!

[image]

I was hoping someone could help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:):

```
func presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(_ suggestions: [String]?,
                          allowedInputMode inputMode: WKTextInputMode,
                                completion completion: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void)
```

The problem seems to be in your last parameter which is String -> Void. You get there `[AnyObject]?` not String.

Comment: Idk. Not me. I'm testing your thing now